# What might cause our application not work? C++

Tags: c++, winapi, directshow

```
void CCaptureDlg::ListDevice()
{
    ((CComboBox *)GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO_DEVICE))->ResetContent();
    HRESULT hr;
    IMoniker * pMoniker =NULL;
    ULONG cFetched;
    ICreateDevEnum * pDevEnum =NULL;

    hr = CoCreateInstance (CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC,
        IID_ICreateDevEnum, (void ** ) &pDevEnum);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Couldn't create system enumerator!");
        return ;
    }

    IEnumMoniker * pClassEnum = NULL;

    hr = pDevEnum->CreateClassEnumerator (CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, &pClassEnum, 0);
    //hr = pDevEnum->CreateClassEnumerator (CLSID_LegacyAmFilterCategory, &pClassEnum, 0);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Couldn't create class enumerator!");
        pDevEnum->Release();
        return ;
    }

    if (pClassEnum == NULL)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("No video capture device was detected.");
        pDevEnum->Release();
        return ;
    }

    while(S_OK == (pClassEnum->Next (1, &pMoniker, &cFetched)))
    {
        IPropertyBag *pBag;
        hr = pMoniker->BindToStorage(0, 0, IID_IPropertyBag, (void **)&pBag);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            CString ss;
            VARIANT var;
            var.vt = VT_BSTR;
            hr = pBag->Read(L"FriendlyName", &var, NULL);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {                
                ss.Format("%S",var.pbstrVal);
                ((CComboBox *)GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO_DEVICE))->AddString(ss);
                SysFreeString(var.bstrVal);
            }
            pBag->Release();
        }
        pMoniker->Release();
    }

    pClassEnum->Release();
    pDevEnum->Release();

}
```

Above is source code of our application, we use it to list all video device, but this application doesn't work on some machine with windows xp installed. it prompts us "invalid port number", Can someone tell me what's the possible reason?

Comment: When stepping through with a debugger, which line fails with the port number message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think of a buggy video capture device which shows this error message, or another part of your code which you did not provide. There is nothing here in this code snippet to do such a prompt.

If you have a weird message box coming out of nowhere, the debugging you can do is to break with debugger without closing the box and check the window call stack, in order to identify the DLL which pops up the message...

Comment: in some debuggers you can break on windows api calls (e.g. CreateMessageBoxW). Just run your application until the debugger breaks at the appropriate api and then check the callstack. I think OllyDbg can do the trick for you.

Comment: Chances are that a simpler thing can be done - without closing the message box, an attached debugger shows the stack, you just need to find the thread of your interest. SDK tools like Spy++ help even with that too.